# Infinite coin flipping

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that two players are flipping the coin (which is assumed to be fair). They continue to flip up to the moment when either of two sequences occurs: HH or TTT. In the first event player 1 wins and in the second player 2 wins. What is the probability that Player 1 wins? The same problem for HHT and THT.

EDIT: I tried to solve this problem via "random-walks" method but unfortunately I realized that this problem does not fit into this scheme. I also tried to get some recurrence relation. On the other hand, I found one version of this problem (but much simpler) and the solution was "by hand". I wonder whether is there a general method which allows to treat all such examples. 
Of course H means "heads" and T stands for "tails".

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, we have a Markov chain with six states, in which every transition probability is $1/2\,{}$:
$$
\begin{array}{cccclll}
& & H \text{ not preceded by }H & \longrightarrow & HH \\
& \nearrow & \updownarrow \\
\text{start} & & \updownarrow & \nwarrow  \\
& \searrow & \updownarrow \\
& & T\text{ not preceded by }T & \longrightarrow &  TT\text{ not preceded by } T & \longrightarrow & TTT
\end{array}
$$

Consider

- $w=\Pr(\text{ultimately }HH \mid \text{now at $H$ not preceded by $H$})$,
- $x=\Pr(\text{ultimately }HH \mid \text{now at $T$ not preceded by $T$})$,
- $y=\Pr(\text{ultimately }HH \mid \text{now at $TT$ not preceded by $T$})$,
- $z=\Pr(\text{ultimately }HH \mid \text{now at ``start''})$.

We have
\begin{align}
w & = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2x \\[8pt]
x & = \frac 1 2 y + \frac 1 2 w \\[8pt]
y & = \frac 1 2 w \\[8pt]
z & = \frac 1 2 w + \frac 1 2 x
\end{align}